How to fix this persistent error on Chrome RDP in Linux?
Has anyone encountered this error when installing a new Chrome RDP on a new instance, and could anyone please help fix this persistent error on Chrome RDP in Linux?
"ERROR:host_starter_base.cc(305)] The caller does not have permission
Extended error information:#The caller does not have permission
Couldn't start host: Permission denied."
Any helpful answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
